# Run parallel program from SAS EG using %macro

Tags: sas

I have some problem to find out if what I want to do is possible or not on SAS EG 7.15.

**Context**

We have splitted a quite big project into several flow process which have each one a program to define a `%macro` statement and a final process flow which contain a program call "EXECUTION" to call all those program in the row in this way :

Flow_Process_1/program:

```
%macro TheFirstOne;
some code
%mend TheFirstOne;
```

---

some other process flow

---

Flow_Process_123/EXECUTION:

```
%TheFirstOne;
%TheSecondOne;
%TheThirdOne;...
```

The advantage is that all is splitted and easy to execute just by a click on the first process flow -> SHIFT+Click on the last one and everything is going to be executed. Also you have a unique log file of all the different program in one. And everything works perfectly.

**The Problem**

The problem is that we have a quite long execution (in time) that we wanted to split into parallel process which is not really hard to set with the "Allow Parallel execution on the same server" option and this feature also work like a charm when you try to execute some program which work on their own.

However, with the way we are working, the first process (thread i would say) knows about our `%macro` definition and works perfectly, but the second or any other one don't know about them and give error like :

> WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro xxxxxxx not resolved.

since we never execute the program before which define this macro before.

**My attempt**

I tried to use the Autoexec feature but I have to copy the definition of every macro (5000 + lines) inside if that it works for every parallel process. I also looked into SAS code to run a flow process in a program but it looks like it does not exist, or I did not find it.

I'm quite sure that senior in SAS will say that is not the way we should use SAS EG, but we did that way and I just would like to know if there is a solution to let know to other process the definition of all `%macro` define previously.

Comment: Instead of manually copying the macro code, why don't you put all of the definitions in one file and just use the %include statement with the autoexec feature?

Comment: Because if we change a part of any program, we would have to change 2 file, which it will be quite long. Even more in a 5000+ lines file.it would works, but the Autoexec feature would be exactly the same at the end

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you change something in the macros, you will change just the definition file. If you change something in the execute script, you will just change that script. Why would a change have to be done in 2 files ?

Comment: Then maybe I do not understand what you are trying to say. If we keep our way of split, can we just auto export a standalone file *.sas and then %include to have just one of every program ? Otherwise it is not a solution since we have to change 2 files.

Comment: Ok I do understand what you are saying. but it means to have a single file for a big amount of definition of `%macro` which it will be a nightmare to maintain

Comment: You could put each macro in its own file and then use include them within a main include file. One way or the other you have to maintain those macro files anyway :)

Comment: Well if I correctly understand what you are saying, then it would be really easy, but maybe I missunderstand how works `%include` when I looked into. Don't I have to export every program from a project to be able to use it ? Well from Chris Hemedinger `If your programs are simply embedded in the SAS Enterprise Guide project (and not saved as separate files), then you cannot programmatically reference them from other program nodes in the project.` so i think I can't actually. source :https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Call-Other-SAS-Programs-Within-a-Single-Project/td-p/151926

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199377/discussion-between-python-r-sas-and-frankich).